# PHP Json returns null

Tags: php, json

I am facing a strange problem with Json. I am sending json code from my server to another server.

Below is the simple file code that is located at remote server:

```
$jsonObj = json_decode($_GET['obj']);

foreach($jsonObj as $item){
}

echo json_encode(array('message' => 'I returned'));
exit;
```

When i directly run the remote file, it prints the correct result. However, when i call the file from my server, it returns null. The strange thing is, when i remove empty foreach loop code then my server receives the correct value.

What can be the problems?

Comment: What is the full URL you're using to test it locally?

Comment: show whats is `$_GET['obj']`

Comment: But your current output has nothing to do with your input.

Comment: The url that calls the remote file looks like this **example.com/service.php?action=add&obj={"first_name":"Salman","last_name":"Javaid"}&user_id=2**

Comment: Are you `urlencode($json)` your JSON? Perhaps it'd be better in a POST call?

Comment: @Jono20201 you are right. i should had put urlencode(). Thanks